# How can you make `first` return a `Failure` if both f and g fail?

Tags: scala, concurrency, promise, future

An example from the official scala [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html):

```
def first[T](f: Future[T], g: Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  val p = promise[T]
  f onSuccess {
    case x => p.trySuccess(x)
  }
  g onSuccess {
    case x => p.trySuccess(x)
  }
  p.future
}
```

> Note that in this implementation, if neither f nor g succeeds, then
>   first(f, g) never completes (either with a value or with an
>   exception).

It gives us a warning, but no corresponding solution. How can you make `first` return a `Failure` if both f and g fail?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is there particular reason to have two futures running concurrently and resolve with the first that returns? This introduces non-determinism in the execution of code and cannot be solved elegantly (that is, without introducing variable to track state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution: where you need to find the first successful one amongst a list. Or a failure if all fails.

The solution is a bit effectful by nature, would be happy to see pure functional implementation:

```
def second[T](ls: Seq[Future[T]]): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  val size = ls.size
  val count = new AtomicInteger(0)

  ls.foreach(x => x onComplete{
    case Success(a) => p.tryCompleteWith(x)
    case Failure(y) =>  if(count.incrementAndGet() == size) p.tryCompleteWith(x)
  })
  p.future
}
```

The below prints `2` as expected:

```
second(List(Future{ Thread.sleep(5000); 1}, Future{Thread.sleep(3000) ;2}, Future{throw new RuntimeException})) onComplete{
  case Success(x) => println(x)
  case Failure(y) => y.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what you mean by: `The solution is a bit effectful by nature...` ?

Comment: @KevinMeredith What I mean is, that I maintain state (`count`) and then modify its state with time. This is a side-effect. Ideally I would have preferred a way avoiding it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could do the job, although it's not based on the same logic as your example (this solution is **wrong**, check the **Update**)

```
def first[T](f: Future[T], g: Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]
  p.completeWith(f.fallbackTo(g))
  p.future
}
```

If both fails, `first` [holds](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@fallbackTo[U%3E:T](that:scala.concurrent.Future[U]):scala.concurrent.Future[U]) the throwable coming from `f`.

**Update** (based on @Jatin's comment):
My first solution is wrong, because if the `f` future never completes, then even if `g` does, `first` never completes either. This updated solution completes the `Promise` nondeterministically with the first completed value:

```
def first[T](f: Future[T], g: Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]
  p.completeWith(Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(f.fallbackTo(g),g.fallbackTo(f))))
  p.future
}
```

Comment: It has a flaw. That if `g` gets completed quickly and `f` takes longer, then the returned future is never complete

Comment: hmm, I don't see your point, sorry. Could you elaborate? `first(Future{Thread.sleep(1); 5}, Future[Int]{1})` seems to work just fine

Comment: Try with `first(Future{Thread.sleep(100000); 5}, Future[Int]{1})`. It will wait forever